# Including disturbance rejection in GEKKO MPC

Tags: gekko

I am trying to implement an MPC algorithm using GEKKO MPC to compare against my own MPC implementation. I have managed to perform the set point changes without a problem however, when I try to include steps in a disturbance the controlled variable does not return to steady state (a value of zero for deviation variables). This would make me think that I need to include a command which allows feedback? I am unsure.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

t = numpy.linspace(0,300,100)
m = GEKKO(remote = False)
m.time = t
# Parameters

T1 = m.Param(value = 53.97272679974334)
T2 = m.Param(value = 48.06851424706475)
T3 = m.Param(value = 38.48651254747577)
T4 = m.Param(value = 31.018933652439845)
k1 = m.Param(value = 5.51)
k2 = m.Param(value = 6.58)
γ1bar = m.Param(value = 0.333)
γ2bar = m.Param(value = 0.307)
A1 = m.Param(value = 730)
A2 = m.Param(value = 730)
A3 = m.Param(value = 730)
A4 = m.Param(value = 730)
v1bar = m.Param(value = 60)
v2bar = m.Param(value = 60)

# Manipulated variable
v1 = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=100)
v1.STATUS = 1  
#v1.DCOST = 0.1 
#v2.DMAX = 20   

v2 = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=100)
v2.STATUS = 1  
#v2.DCOST = 0.1 
#v2.DMAX = 20   

γ1 = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=1)
γ1.STATUS = 1  
#γ1.DCOST = 0.1 
#v2.DMAX = 20   

γ2 = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=1)
γ2.STATUS = 1  
#γ2.DCOST = 0.1 
#v2.DMAX = 20   

d = numpy.ones(t.shape)
d[0:10] = 0

d22 = numpy.zeros(t.shape)

d1 = m.Param(name='d1', value=d)  # Disturbance
d2 = m.Param(name='d2', value=d22)  # Disturbance

m.options.CV_TYPE = 2 # squared error

# Controlled Variable
h1 = m.CV(value=0)
h1.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
h1.SP = 1    # set point
h1.TR_INIT = 1 # set point trajectory
h1.TAU = 1   # time constant of trajectory
h1.BIAS = 1
h1.FSTATUS = 1

h2 = m.CV(value=0)
h2.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
h2.SP = 0  # set point
h2.TR_INIT = 1 # set point trajectory
h2.TAU = 1     # time constant of trajectory
h2.BIAS = 1
h2.FSTATUS = 1

h3 = m.CV(value=0)
h3.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
h3.SP = 0     # set point
h3.TR_INIT = 1 # set point trajectory
h3.TAU = 1     # time constant of trajectory
h3.BIAS = 1
h3.FSTATUS = 1

h4 = m.CV(value=0)
h4.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
h4.SP = 0     # set point
h4.TR_INIT = 1 # set point trajectory
h4.TAU = 1     # time constant of trajectory
h4.BIAS = 1
h4.FSTATUS = 1

m.Equation(h1.dt() == -(1/T1)*h1 + (A3/(A1*T3))*h3 + (γ1bar*k1*v1)/A1 + (γ1*k1*v1bar)/A1)
m.Equation(h2.dt() == -(1/T2)*h2 + (A4/(A2*T4))*h4 + (γ2bar*k2*v2)/A2 + (γ2*k2*v2bar)/A2)
m.Equation(h3.dt() == -(1/T3)*h3 + ((1-γ2bar)*k2*v2)/A3 - k2*v2bar*γ2/A3 - (k1*d1)/A3) 
m.Equation(h4.dt() == -(1/T4)*h4 + ((1-γ1bar)*k1*v1)/A4 - k1*v1bar*γ1/A4 - (k2*d2)/A4)

m.options.IMODE = 6 # control

m.solve(disp=False,debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `h1.SP = 0` instead of `1` to set the objective to drive it back to 1. Also, these options are not needed if `h4.TR_INIT = 0` to create a setpoint that is zero everywhere (not a reference trajectory).

```
h4.TAU = 1
h4.BIAS = 1
h4.FSTATUS = 1
```

I also added lower bounds of zero for each of the height CVs with `lb=0`. There is a move on `v2` when the disturbance starts. It appears that the controller can't resolve this offset. Is this the correct response?

[image: MPC results]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

t = numpy.linspace(0,300,100)
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = t

T1 = m.Param(value = 53.97272679974334)
T2 = m.Param(value = 48.06851424706475)
T3 = m.Param(value = 38.48651254747577)
T4 = m.Param(value = 31.018933652439845)
k1 = m.Param(value = 5.51)
k2 = m.Param(value = 6.58)
γ1bar = m.Param(value = 0.333)
γ2bar = m.Param(value = 0.307)
A1 = m.Param(value = 730)
A2 = m.Param(value = 730)
A3 = m.Param(value = 730)
A4 = m.Param(value = 730)
v1bar = m.Param(value = 60)
v2bar = m.Param(value = 60)

# Manipulated variable
v1 = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=100)
v1.STATUS = 1  
#v1.DCOST = 0.1 
#v2.DMAX = 20   

v2 = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=100)
v2.STATUS = 1  
#v2.DCOST = 0.1 
#v2.DMAX = 20   

γ1 = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=1)
γ1.STATUS = 1  
#γ1.DCOST = 0.1 
#v2.DMAX = 20   

γ2 = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=1)
γ2.STATUS = 1  
#γ2.DCOST = 0.1 
#v2.DMAX = 20   

d = numpy.ones(t.shape)
d[0:10] = 0

d22 = numpy.zeros(t.shape)

d1 = m.Param(name='d1', value=d)  # Disturbance
d2 = m.Param(name='d2', value=d22)  # Disturbance

m.options.CV_TYPE = 2 # squared error

# Controlled Variable
h1 = m.CV(value=0,lb=0)
h1.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
h1.SP = 0    # set point
h1.TR_INIT = 0 # set point trajectory
#h1.TAU = 1   # time constant of trajectory
#h1.BIAS = 1
#h1.FSTATUS = 1

h2 = m.CV(value=0,lb=0)
h2.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
h2.SP = 0  # set point
h2.TR_INIT = 0 # set point trajectory
#h2.TAU = 1     # time constant of trajectory
#h2.BIAS = 1
#h2.FSTATUS = 1

h3 = m.CV(value=0,lb=0)
h3.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
h3.SP = 0     # set point
h3.TR_INIT = 0 # set point trajectory
#h3.TAU = 1     # time constant of trajectory
#h3.BIAS = 1
#h3.FSTATUS = 1

h4 = m.CV(value=0,lb=0)
h4.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
h4.SP = 0     # set point
h4.TR_INIT = 0 # set point trajectory
#h4.TAU = 1     # time constant of trajectory
#h4.BIAS = 1
#h4.FSTATUS = 1

m.Equation(h1.dt() == -(1/T1)*h1 + (A3/(A1*T3))*h3 + (γ1bar*k1*v1)/A1 + (γ1*k1*v1bar)/A1)
m.Equation(h2.dt() == -(1/T2)*h2 + (A4/(A2*T4))*h4 + (γ2bar*k2*v2)/A2 + (γ2*k2*v2bar)/A2)
m.Equation(h3.dt() == -(1/T3)*h3 + ((1-γ2bar)*k2*v2)/A3 - k2*v2bar*γ2/A3 - (k1*d1)/A3) 
m.Equation(h4.dt() == -(1/T4)*h4 + ((1-γ1bar)*k1*v1)/A4 - k1*v1bar*γ1/A4 - (k2*d2)/A4)

m.options.IMODE = 6 # control

m.solve(disp=True)

plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,d1.value,'k-',label='Disturbance')
plt.ylabel('Disturbance'); plt.grid(); plt.legend()

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,h1.value,'r-',label='Height 1')
plt.plot(m.time,h2.value,'g--',label='Height 2')
plt.plot(m.time,h3.value,'b:',label='Height 3')
plt.plot(m.time,h3.value,'k--',alpha=0.5,label='Height 4')
plt.ylabel('CVs'); plt.grid(); plt.legend()

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(m.time,v1.value,'r-',label='MV 1a')
plt.plot(m.time,v2.value,'g--',label='MV 2a')
plt.plot(m.time,γ1.value,'b:',label='MV 1b')
plt.plot(m.time,γ2.value,'k--',alpha=0.5,label='MV 2b')
plt.ylabel('MVs'); plt.grid(); plt.legend()

plt.show()
```